# Create Dataframe from existing Dataframe using list of columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I am new to data frames and Python. I have an existing data frame with 16 columns. I have a list of columns I want (this will change  so the column names will be in a list). Can I create a new data frame using the list and original data frame?

This is what I tried:

```
df = df.select([c for c in df.columns 
                    if c not in columns])
    return df
```

Error message:

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: `new_df = df['your_list_of_columns']`

Comment: Actually, my list of columns are in list ( which will change ) so I need a generic script that works

Comment: Yes, just pass the list there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "reindex" method:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({f"col{i}": i  for i in range(6)}, index=list(range(6)) ) # test data

df:
   col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0     0     1     2     3     4     5
1     0     1     2     3     4     5
2     0     1     2     3     4     5
3     0     1     2     3     4     5
4     0     1     2     3     4     5
5     0     1     2     3     4     5

reqcols=["col1","col5","col0"]                                                                                      
df2= df.reindex(reqcols,axis="columns")                                                                                  
df2: 
   col1  col5  col0
0     1     5     0
1     1     5     0
2     1     5     0
3     1     5     0
4     1     5     0
5     1     5     0
```

Answer (score 0):

As was already suggested in the comments to your question, you can use a list to slice up the dataframe.

```py
columns = ... # your list of columns to exclude
df_result = df_init.loc[:, [c for c in df_init if c not in columns]].copy()
```

Adding `.copy()` seems to be good practice -- otherwise, once you change your `df_result`, that change can flow over to `df_init`.